# How to add a command in CMake but not run it?

Tags: makefile, cmake

The idea is to define a detached "examples" target in the CMakeLists.txt that would not get executed when running:

```
make
```

But that would build the examples when doing

```
make examples
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution: set **EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL** on the "add_executable" command.

This is what I had to write to solve my "examples" build:

```
add_custom_target(examples)
add_executable(hello EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL hello.cpp)
add_dependencies(examples hello)
```

When running "make", the **hello** executable is not built.
When running "make examples", **hello** is built.